# Timeout when I try to debug a python file in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I'm trying to debug my python files with vscode and I always receive a pop-up indication that there is a "Time out waiting for launcher to connect".

My launch.json is

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense para saber los atributos posibles.
    // Mantenga el puntero para ver las descripciones de los existentes atributos.
    // Para más información, visite: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: archivo actual",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried to modify the console option as other topics recommends but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**There is nothing wrong with your *launch.json***.

without any other additional information, I suggest you close all terminals you are using

[image]

And start debugging again.

[image]